# Set cookies from first response to next request

Tags: 7

I am newbie to drupal and node.js. I am connecting drupal with node.js server. What I am trying to do is that to get the cookie from the the node.js server response and I need to set these cookies over to the next request to the node.js server

```
function sample_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $request_url = "http://localhost/api/authenticate";  //Link to Node.Js server
  $sig =  hash_hmac('sha512', 'secret', 'secret');//hashed the api key using sha512 algoritham
  $options = array(
                'method' => 'POST',
                'data' =>  'apikey='.$sig,//api key for authenticaton between nodejs and drupal application
                'timeout' => 15,
                'headers' => array('Content-Type'=> 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        );
    $result = drupal_http_request($request_url, $options);     
}
```

I am authenticating the request with an api key with node.js server. node.js server create a session cookie with the help of passportjs module. I want get the cookie from the the node.js server and pass the cookie with the next request. That is I want get the cookie from the above function and then to send the cookie along with the request in below function so that only node.js server can authenticate with drupal app.

```
    function sample_submit1($form, &$form_state) { 
      $request_url = "http://localhost/login";  //Link to Node.Js server
      $options = array(
                    'method' => 'GET',
                    'timeout' => 15,
                    'headers' => array('Content-Type'=> 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
            );
        $result = drupal_http_request($request_url, $options);
        drupal_set_message(t($result->data));
}
```

Is there any way or any better way to do this? Any insight into this would highly be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: From a quick look around, a string of cookies should be present in `$result->headers['set-cookie']` from your first request and after parsing out what cookie(s) you want to return, it/they can then be sent in `$options['headers']['set-cookie']` in your second request.

Comment: (headers are supposed to be case insensitive so probably a print_r($result->headers) might be a good thing to check if, for example, you have `Set-Cookie` instead, too)